# filter Multi-Dimensional array from single array

Tags: php, arrays

i have Multi-Dimensional array  and
i have another one that have some of the id that exist in the first Multi-Dimensional

now what i need is to use filter function to filter any element that exist in the second single array

my  Multi-Dimensional array is :

```
 $Base = array
  (
  array("aa",1),
  array("bb",2),
  array("cc",3),
  array("dd",4),
  array("ee",5),
  array("ff",6),
  array("gg",7),
  );
```

and the another one is :

```
  $child = array(1,4,5);
```

what i expect now to filter the array and get

```
$new = array
  (
  array("aa",1),
  array("dd",4),
  array("ee",5) 
 );
```

Comment: Have a look at [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter). You can use a callback that has `$child` available to it and just return `in_array($arg[1], $child)`.

Comment: yes that what i need but  i couldn't get the logic idea to return the true value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
$Base = array(
  array("aa",1),
  array("bb",2),
  array("cc",3),
  array("dd",4),
  array("ee",5),
  array("ff",6),
  array("gg",7),
);
$child = array(1,4,5);

$filtered = array_filter($Base, function($arg) use ($child){
    //return if arg1 is in $child
    return in_array($arg[1], $child);
});
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qqcl3e